# ExtJS remove listener

Tags: extjs, extjs4, dom-events

I'm having difficulty getting this to work:

```
var fn = function(){};

Ext.select('ul > li').on('click',fn);
// works

Ext.select('ul > li').un('click',fn);
//doesn't work
```

'un'/'removeListener' does not work. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, `Ext.select` creates a [flyweight object](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Element-static-method-fly), which does not remember event listeners. Thus, they cannot be removed later.

You need to create real `Ext.Element`s by setting the second parameter to `true`:

```
var fn = function(){};

Ext.select('ul > li', true).on('click',fn);

Ext.select('ul > li', true).un('click',fn);
```

Unfortunately, the docs are not very clear about this.